# SQL inserting one less apostrophe in to client than on my test server

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, insert, apostrophe

I have a script inserting a formula into a field in my database.  The script looks like this:

```
insert into Export..DataDictionary 
values(100001,  'Modifier 3',   'Modifier 3',   476,    'IsNull(Modifier_3, '''')', 'Char', NULL,   NULL,   'Y',    NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL    ,'N',   NULL,   'Y',    'Modifier_3')
```

In my test server, it comes out correctly and the string put in the field is: IsNull(Modifier_3, '')

However, when I run the same insert on the client, the string inserts with one less apostrophe and comes out as: IsNull(Modifier_3, ')

What could be the issue here?

Comment: How is the script getting to and getting executed on the client's system?  Be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run into situations with quotes inside strings I use QUOTENAME.

In your case I would do like this

```
DECLARE @item As varchar(100) = 'IsNull(Modifier_3, {0})';
SET @item = REPLACE(@item, '{0}', QUOTENAME('', ''''));

INSERT INTO Export..DataDictionary
VALUES (..., @item, ...)
```

You can of course make it a one-liner if you like

```
REPLACE('IsNull(Modifier_3, {0})', '{0}', QUOTENAME('', ''''))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have two apostrophe the right way, I believe, is to put six apostrophe in your query.I really don't know how it works in your own server.

```
insert into Export..DataDictionary 
values(100001,  'Modifier 3',   'Modifier 3',   476,    'IsNull(Modifier_3, '''''')', 'Char', NULL,   NULL,   'Y',    NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL    ,'N',   NULL,   'Y',    'Modifier_3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?
Please test the following in both environments

```
select ''
select ''''
select ''''''
```

For me I get
nothing
'
''

this throws a syntax error

```
select '''
```

more test

```
declare @var varchar(10);
set @var = null;
select @var;
select IsNull(@var, '')
select IsNull(@var, '''')
select IsNull(@var, '''''')
set @var = 'var';
select @var;
select IsNull(@var, '''')
```